# Uncompressing a .zip file in app | Appcelerator | Titanium

Tags: android, ios, compression, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am looking for a module (for both iOS and Android) that would let me uncompress a .zip in my app. As for the Appcelerator configuration, I am running Titanium SDK 5.1.1GA and testing on iOS 9.2 / Android 5.1.1.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ti.compression`  Module  for both `Android` and `iOS`

http://gitt.io/component/ti.compression